# How does python list.sort() function actually work?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Look at the following code:

```
arr = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
arr1 = arr
arr1.sort()
print(arr, arr1)
```

The expected output is:

> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

As, arr1 is getting sorted and not arr.

Although, the output is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

How come both lists are getting sorted?

Comment: `arr1 = arr` doesn't copy the list. It just makes a new reference to the same object in memory, so changes to one reflect on the other. Use `arr1 = arr[:]` to copy the list using slice notation. Then, when you call `arr1.sort()`, it will only mutate `arr1` in-place, leaving `arr` unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort()` is in-place function in python and lists are pass by reference. So, if one array is getting sorted in-place it will change another, too.

If you want to prevent that, you can use:

```
arr = arr1[:]
```

or

```
import copy
arr = copy.deepcopy(arr1)
```

Comment: ... or `arr = arr1.copy()`, which is the One Obvious Way to do a list copy ...